# C++: Crashes on trying to write to file

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. The purpose of the program is to give the user an option to open a file, write to it, then read the file that was just written to and display back what is now in the file. When it'll take in the user input, but after hitting enter it will crash. I think it's crashing when it tries to read the file?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 80
#include <iostream>
int main(void)
{
    FILE * pFile;
    int c; // variable to hold character input by user
    char sentence[SIZE]; // create char array
    char filename[SIZE]; //create filename array
    char filesentence[SIZE];
    int i = 0; // initialize counter i
    int number;
    std::cout << "Give a number. 1 for file. Anything else for standard.";
    std::cin >> number;
    getchar();
    
    if(number==1)
    {
    
        puts("Enter filename to append: ");
        while ((i < SIZE-1) && (c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        filename[i++] = c;}
    
        filename[i]= '\0';
    
        //fgetc(sentence,80,stdin);
        pFile=fopen(filename,"w+");
    
        puts("Give a sentence to place in file:");
        while ((i < SIZE-1) && (c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        sentence[i++] = c;}
    
        sentence[i]= '\0';
    
        fputs(sentence,pFile);
    
        i=0;
        do {
          c = fgetc (pFile);
          filesentence[i++] = c;
          printf(filesentence);   
        } while (c != EOF);

        fclose (pFile);
    }
    else
    {
    
        // prompt user to enter line of text
        puts("Enter a line of text:");
    
        // use getchar to read each character
        while ((i < SIZE-1) && (c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        sentence[i++] = c;}
    
        sentence[i]= '\0';
    
        // terminate string
        // use puts to display sentence
    
        puts("\nThe line entered was:");
        puts(sentence);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that? Didn't your debugger show exactly where it crashed and why? And even show an error message? Also this kind of mix of C++ and C functions is quite messy. Why not actually write C++?

Comment: Not sure. Just reading it while running I can get to giving the filename, and then the text to write to the file...but then after that it crashes when it tries to read the file back and output it

Comment: And the line by line debugging showed which point as the problem?

Comment: Shows no problem. It crashes while running.

Comment: So when you run it with debugger it works, but without doesn't? Are you sure you know what debugging means?

Comment: if you are going to write in c++, use `string` instead of `char`. also, I suggest you use symbolic constants instead of macros for the `SIZE`. Example: `const int size = 80`. you should also use `using namespace std;` so you dont have to keep writing `std::`

Comment: In addition to what FluorescentGreen5 wrote: You should learn actual C++. What you write is essentially C. Avoid arrays, we have std::vector for that. Don't write "clever" lines such as sentence[i++] = c, those are two separate commands, sentence[i] = c and i++. Readability is key, not a small amount of lines. In this case, you might omit the i++ and use a for loop instead of a while loop to increment it. Declare variables where they are used, especially something like an index i. This one should only live within the loop, another reason for for loops. Otherwise you don't know when it dies.

Comment: As for FluorescentGreen5 's recommendation to use "using namespace std;", I advise against this. STD is big and this might create name collisions. Use something like "using std::cout;" for everything you actually use out of the namespace, lets you omit the namespace while making it clear where it came from. As for your actual problem, listen to Sami Kuhmonen and read a tutorial on debuggers. Which IDE are you using? If you don't know about debuggers, have you tried system messages throughout the program to isolate the error?

Comment: @Aziuth hmm, I wonder where i learnt `using namespace std` from. Compilers need to provide warnings for when we use bad coding practice.

Comment: @FluorescentGreen5 It's somewhat common in use. For example, in eclipse, the standard Hello World program does it. And it's not THAT bad of a practise. For other libraries, you might want to simply fully include the namespace, especially when they are quite narrow and focused on something, excluding the possibility of collisions and making it easy to guess where stuff comes from.